# Продолжить цикл после выполнения условия

Tags: python, while

Привет. Надо сделать так чтобы печаталось а если секудна четная и b если секунда нечетная. Но while лишь выполняет первое условие и застревает на нем. Да и не идет цикл как бесконечный. Как исправить код?

```
import datetime
minutes = datetime.datetime.now()
devi = minutes.second % 2
one = 'a'
two = 'b'


while devi > 0:
    print(one)
else:
    print(two)

print(devi)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш пример можно исправить как то так:

```
import datetime

one = 'a'
two = 'b'

while True:
    minutes = datetime.datetime.now()
    devi = minutes.second % 2
    if devi > 0:
        print(one)
    else:
        print(two)
    print(devi)
```

Comment: В данном случае удобнее воспользоваться тернарным оператором: `print(one if minutes.second % 2 else two)` вместо `if .. else ...`

Comment: @MaxU, несомненно. Однако, вопрос был в другом, и, на мой взгляд, до тернарных операторов надо "дорасти", когда уже будет уверенное понятие, когда лучше, а когда хуже. На начальном этапе это может сослужить плохую пользу. Имхо, конечно же:)

Comment: тоже мне "rocket science" - по-моему лучше сразу учиться хорошим манерам ;-)